# Spring Boot: getting wrong format of double qoutes

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am writing an app in which I need to send some data from Spring Boot controller to template by Thymeleaf.

I did not have problems until I wanted to send some JSON.

Double qoute(`"`) is changed to `&quot;`.

Because of that I am getting an error.

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/statistics")
public String viewStatistics(Model model) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = statisticsService.getTaskNamePercentageMap();
    System.out.println(jsonArray);
    model.addAttribute("taskNamePercentageMap", jsonArray);
    return "statistics/main";
}
```

**System.out.println(jsonArray) output:**

```
[{"low":33,"name":"Tenis"},{"low":100,"name":"Rugby"}]
```

**JavaScript code in statistics/main template:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var json =[[${taskNamePercentageMap}]];
        /*... TO BE CONTINUED ...*/
    });
```

**Variable "a" in Chrome developer tab Sources:**

```
var b = JSON.stringify([{&quot;low&quot;:33,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Tenis&quot;},{&quot;low&quot;:100,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Rugby&quot;}]);
```

Can someone tell me where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html), at section `8.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var json = [(${taskNamePercentageMap})];
```

From [Thymeleaf 3.0 docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining)

> Note that, while [[...]] corresponds to th:text (i.e. result will be HTML-escaped), [(...)] corresponds to th:utext and will not perform any HTML-escaping.